# Can't view Custom Activity in Journey Builder, but others can

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

Client has a Custom Activity in Journey Builder... when I open the Journey I see "Unknown Custom Activity" and I cannot open the activity or see any details.  When the client logs in, they can see it and apply it to the Journey.

We have the same level of permissions in the platform (Admin + MC Admin).

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you licensed yourself in the licensing section of the Installed Package?

Comment: Do you have the API Permission on User Level?

Comment: @Macca - I have not, so we will try it.

Answer (score 1):

The “Unknown custom activity” error means that the custom activity endpoint was unreachable. Perhaps the custom app has IP restrictions or was offline at that moment.